# Extraer informacion de una web con login usando php y curl

Tags: php, curl, scraping

estoy empezando a aprender un poco de curl y estoy intentando realizar un projecto de scraping.

Me idea es conseguir logearme en una web, y despues obtener los datos de la web.

El código que estoy usando es este:

```
<?php 
$username="usu@gmail.com"; 
$password="contraseña"; 
$url="https://lobby.ikariam.gameforge.com/"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;  

$texto = file_get_contents("https://s2-us.ikariam.gameforge.com/?view=island&islandId=2216");
echo $texto;

curl_close($ch);

 ?>
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo php, me devuelve esto:

```
405 Not Allowed
nginx/1.16.1
```

Y cuando intento leer los datos de la web con el file_get_contents, me indica que no estoy logeado.
Me falla algo de la parte de curl? El problema esta en la parte de las cookies?El fichero cookie.txt esta vacio.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

El login de esa web no funciona de esa manera.

Funciona con una petición POST hacia `https://lobby.ikariam.gameforge.com/api/users` y mandando como datos un JSON con (entre otras cosas) el usuario y password.

Por ejemplo, este es el JSON que manda con la petición:

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "email":"un email",
        "password":"el password"
    }
    ,"language":"en"
    ,"kid":""
    ,"autoLogin":false
}
```

Te recomiendo utilizar las herramientas de desarrollo de Firefox/Chrome. En concreto la pestaña de network, donde podrás ver las peticiones que se van realizando.

Para aprender scrapping, conviene empezar con una web estática. Las webs dináminas son más complicadas, especialmente si disponen de un login.

Muchas peticiones hoy en día se hacen via ajax y tienen mecanismos de seguridad, como tokens [CSRF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).